# Vue 3 composition API debounce function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, debouncing, vue-composition-api

I am trying to create a reusable debounce function in Vue 3 using the composition API but am struggling to get it to work.

This is what I have so far:

**debounce.js**

```js
const debounce = (fn, delay) => {
  let timeout

  return (...args) => {
    if (timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      fn(...args)
    }, delay)
  }
}

export default debounce
```

**BaseComponent.vue**

```html
<template>
  <input type="text" @input="onInput" />
</template>

<script>
import debounce from './debounce'

export default {
  setup() {
    const onInput = () => {
      debounce(() => {
        console.log('debug')
      }, 500)
    }

    return { onInput }
  }
}
</script>
```

The callback passed to the debounce function is not being triggered. I'm not seeing the output in the console.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `debounce` function you have is a [higher-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) function which generates and returns a new function.  That generated function is the one that should be used as an event handler to implement the debouncing behavior that you want.

Call `debounce` only once, and set that generated debouncer function to be used as the event handler:

```js
setup() {
  const onInput = debounce(() => {
    console.log('debug')
  }, 500)
  return { onInput }
}
```

Otherwise, the handler calls `debounce` again each time it's triggered, and generates a new debouncer function each time, with no relation to the last one.